# Getting this login issue in app only when i download from playstore

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When test the functionality by generating apk all the features are working fine, but when i download from playstore its getting the below issue in login

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
at c.c.a.d.g.a(Unknown Source:3)
at com.my.packagename.Activity.Login_Activity.a(Unknown Source:155)
at l.g$b$a$a.run(Unknown Source:37)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Please provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

For testing, Are you generating a debug build or release build?
Since you can only upload release build on the playstore, make sure you are testing with a release build in case the problem lies in the release build only.

Also to debug your release build you can add `debuggable = true` in your manifest to check logs. NOTE: do not upload to play store with `debuggable` set to true